# Error while building Jhipster project to deploy on kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, jhipster

I am facing issues while building a jhipster project to deploy on Kubernetes. 
I am following this [link](https://www.jhipster.tech/kubernetes/).

Below are my logs:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.buildImage (BuildMojo.java:185)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.BuildMojo.execute (BuildMojo.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:252)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute (AbstractDockerMojo.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.99.100:2376 [/192.168.99.100] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

I do not have much knowledge on docker/kubernetes.

**Update-1**
I tried `docker images` command as suggested in the answer. It used to work earlier but not it isn't working. I am getting following error while running `docker images` command.

```
error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.37/images/json: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: is `192.168.99.100` the IP-address of your kubernetes?

Comment: I don't have kubernetes installed on local machine. I don't know from where it picked up this IP. Kubernetes is installed on different machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Docker installed and running in order to build the Docker image for the app.  The error says that it can't connect to a running Docker instance.

On Windows, due to lack of named pipes, you may have to tune settings for Docker and turn on “Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS”.  ([Source](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#-building-and-running-a-docker-image-of-your-application))

Comment: THis is the problem I do have docker isntalled I managed to run this query yesterday. When I started today this is failing. and I also restarted the machine twice. I can see docker --version but this thing fails.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I added a note to the answer about that. Also, does another docker command such as `docker images` work?

Comment: Yes, I am on windows 10, and earlier docker images used to work but now I am facing the issue, updated in my question.

Comment: docker image and docker --version is working fine but docker images doesn't work, does this mean that my host is failing to communicate with docker VM ?

Comment: Well I made it work, I change the url in the DOCKER_HOST from tcp//192.168.99.100:2376 to tcp://localhost:2375 and it started working, I am not sure if this is the right fix or not to the problem that I was facing. Please advise.